# Получить случайную строку sqlite, которая удовлетворяет условию WHERE

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Есть база данных sqlite. На данный момент весит около 0.5 Гб и содержит ~2 млн строк. Этот объем постоянно увеличивается и в перспективе будет около 10 млн строк.

Необходимо получать случайную строку, которая будет удовлетворять условию (одна ячейка имеет тип данных BOOLEAN и хранит в себе 0 или 1).

Стандартная конструкция `SELECT * FROM table WHERE blabla = 0 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;` не может быть применена ввиду колоссальной прожорливости ресурсов и времени.

Почти идеально подошло такое решение

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
LIMIT 1 
OFFSET ABS(RANDOM()) % MAX((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table), 1)
```

Но тут нет возможности добавить условие для строки (или просто я не смог его добавить).

Comment: применить `WHERE blabla = 0` к таблице и подзапросу в `OFFSET`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE blabla = 0
LIMIT 1 
OFFSET ABS(RANDOM()) % MAX((SELECT COUNT(*) 
                            FROM table
                            WHERE blabla = 0), 1)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сам бы не допер, что в этой части тоже надо прописать WHERE `MAX((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE blabla = 0), 1)`